# Files with unexpected infinite loop

Tags: c, file

I have used structures to create complex numbers and the function is giving the result of summation..After doing that,I tried to use files store data in complextoplam.txt.Before in "r" mode I stored data in complextoplam.txt with "w" mode and the data is

> ```
>   10.000000 5.000000i
>   8.000000 9.000000i
>   Sum=18.000000+14.000000i
> ```

After storing data in text file,I would like to read data and printing in console screen but an error occurs in this part.When I do while loop using fscanf and EOF,the loop is not finishing and it is going to an infinite loop.Why my programme is acting like that.I think your thoughts will improve me.Kind regards.

```
#pragma warning (disable :4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Complex {
    double real;
    double img;
};
struct Complex c1, c2,c3;
void Toplam(struct Complex c1, struct Complex c2)
{
    c3;
    c3.img = c1.img + c2.img;
    c3.real = c1.real + c2.real;
}

int main() {

    /*c1, c2;
      printf("Write complex c1.\n");
      scanf("%lf %lf", &c1.real, &c1.img);
      printf("Write complex c2.\n");
      scanf("%lf %lf", &c2.real, &c2.img);
      Toplam(c1, c2);
      printf("Sum=%lf + %lfi", c3.real, c3.img);*/
    //this part is used for only in "w" mode// 
    int i;
    FILE *kp;
    kp = fopen("complextoplam.txt", "r");
    if (kp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File opening error.\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("File opened correctfully.\n");
    while (fscanf(kp,"%lf %lf\n %lf %lf \n%lf %lf\n", &c1.real, &c1.img, 
                  &c2.real, &c2.img,&c3.real, &c3.img) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", c1.real, c1.img, c2.real, c2.img, 
               c3.real, c3.img);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the file data doesn't match the `fscanf` format string, it won't return `EOF`. It returns the number of items successfully parsed.

Comment: Do you really have `Sum=` in the file? You don't have anything in the `fscanf()` format to match that.

Comment: For you `fscanf` you're also missing `i` for the second `%lf`

Comment: Don't put space before `\n` in the format string. That skips over all whitespace, including newlines, so it can't match a newline after it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes!I've got Sum= in my file.Do not forget that I've used this programme for "w" mode before "r" mode and I added those using fprintf.

Answer (score 1):

The format string in your `fscanf` call does not match the format of your file. Because of this, `fscanf` will return the number of values correctly read as opposed to `EOF`.

In order to fix this, change your format string to the following: `"%lf %lfi\n%lf %lfi\nSum=%lf+%lfi"`

Comment: Why the compiler is acting like that?And are there any ways to shorten my code instead of using c1.real, c1.img, c2.real, c2.img, 
               c3.real, c3.img); those parts.